# Get loggedin userinformation in extjs shopware backend

Tags: shopware, shopware5

I know that I can access the javascript var userName everywhere in the extjs backend, cause its defined globally in the themes/Backend/ExtJs/backend/index/header.tpl, to get information about the logged in user. But is there a way to get userId or role of the user in some way (without ajax requests)?

```js
//{block name="backend/order/view/list/list"}
//{$smarty.block.parent}
Ext.define('Shopware.apps.Test.view.List', {

    /**
     * Defines an override applied to a class.
     * @string
     */
    override: 'Shopware.apps.Order.view.list.List',

    getToolbar: function() {

        // get this
        var me = this;

        // get parent action column
        var result = me.callParent( arguments );

        console.log(userName);
    },
});
//{/block}
```

```html
{block name="backend/base/header/javascript" append}
<script type="text/javascript">

    var currentTabState = 'active';
    window.addEventListener('blur', function () {
        currentTabState = 'inactive';
    });

    window.addEventListener('focus', function () {
        currentTabState = 'active';
    });

    var userName = '{$user->name}',
        maxParameterLength = '{$maxParameterLength}';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the user available as Smarty variable, so you can simply access the data from this object.
For this you can subscribe to the PostDispatch event of the order backend controller `Enlight_Controller_Action_PostDispatchSecure_Backend_Order` in a subscriber and then you use the same code as in the `Shopware_Controllers_Backend_Index` to add the `$user` variable.

```js
//{block name="backend/order/view/list/list"}
//{$smarty.block.parent}
Ext.define('Shopware.apps.Test.view.List', {

    /**
     * Defines an override applied to a class.
     * @string
     */
    override: 'Shopware.apps.Order.view.list.List',

    getToolbar: function() {

        // get this
        var me = this;

        // get parent action column
        var result = me.callParent( arguments );
        var userId = '{$user->id}';
        var roleId = '{$user->role->getId()}';

        console.log(userName);
    },
});
//{/block}
```

`{$user->role}` contains the `Shopware\Models\User\Role` model, so you can access all data from this object with the corresponding getters.

If you want to know, which data you have available, just make a debug output in the `\Shopware_Controllers_Backend_Index::indexAction` method, right after the call `$identity = $auth->getIdentity();`

```php
echo '<pre>';
\Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($identity);
echo '</pre>';
exit();
```

Comment: Hi thx for the reply, I tried that already but var userId = '{$user->id}';console.log(1, userId, userName); leads to the following output (1 '' 'Dockware Admin'), so this variables are just empty. I use version 5.7.13

Comment: hey @dnaumann thanks for the hint. to be honest, I did not test my solution. I adjusted the example to make it work. The reason is, the smarty variable is only available in the index controller, so you need to make it available in the order controller context. that should work